# Sorting and Organizing a Dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, text, dictionary, output

I have a dictionary with many, many key/value pairs.

The keys are dates and the values are worldwide top-level domains.

I want to output the dictionary to a text file so that it counts and alpha sorts similar values but only within the same key

```
for example:
*key:     value1:count value2:count*
date1:   au:4   be:12   com:44
date2:   az:4   com:14  net:5
```

Code:

```
with open('access_logshort.txt','rU') as f:
for line in f:
    list1 = re.search(r'(?P<Date>[0-9]{2}/[a-zA-Z]{3}/[0-9]{4})(.+)(GET|POST)\s(http://|https://)([a-zA-Z.]+)(\.)(?P<tld>[a-zA-Z]+)(/).+?"\s200',line)

    if list1 != None:
        print list1.groupdict()
        one_tuple = list1.group(1,7)
        my_dict[one_tuple[0]]=one_tuple[1]

output:
print my_dict
{'09/Mar/2004': 'hu'}
{'09/Mar/2004': 'hu'}
{'09/Mar/2004': 'com'}
{'09/Mar/2004': 'ru'}
{'09/Mar/2004': 'ru'}
{'09/Mar/2004': 'com'}
```

T

Comment: How is your dict structured? Like this: `{'<datetime string>': ['com', 'com', 'org', 'com', 'net', ...], '<datetime string2>: ...}`?

Comment: if I `print my_dict` this is the output: 

    `{'09/Mar/2013': 'hu'}

    {'09/Mar/2013': 'hu'}

    {'09/Mar/2013': 'com'}`

Tho each entry is on a new line

Comment: Given your comment, do you mean a list of dicts?

Comment: @kegewe: paste the output of `print my_dict` in your post, please

Comment: Yes I actually do have a list of dicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suit your case.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from dateutil.parser import parse
import csv
import re

data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

with open('access_logshort.txt','rU') as f:
    for line in f:
        list1 = re.search(r'(?P<Date>[0-9]{2}/[a-zA-Z]{3}/[0-9]{4})(.+)(GET|POST)\s(http://|https://)([a-zA-Z.]+)(\.)(?P<tld>[a-zA-Z]+)(/).+?"\s200',line)

        if list1 is not None:
            date, domain = list1.group(1,7)
            data[date.lower()][domain.lower()] += 1

with open('my_data.csv', 'wb') as ofile:
    # add delimiter='\t' to the argument list of csv.writer if you want 
    # tsv rather than csv
    writer = csv.writer(ofile)

    for key, value in sorted(data.iteritems(), key=lambda x: parse(x[0])):
        domains = sorted(value.iteritems())
        writer.writerow([key] + ['{}:{}'.format(*d) for d in domains])
```

Output:

```
10/Mar/2004,com:2,hu:2,ru:2
09/Mar/2004,com:2,hu:2,ru:2
```

Comment: I should add that the my_dict output I posted is pulling from a shortened text file.  The text file that this program will eventually pull from is thousands of lines long

Comment: so I added `my_list = my_dict.items()` instead of pasting the whole list in and then ran your code, but I'm getting an attribute error

Comment: That's because your `my_dict` is a list, not a dict :)

Comment: I really thought there was a simple way to just add the search results to one dictionary and then sort the resulting dictionary.  A 2-dimensional dictionary?

Comment: My updated answer _does_ give you an easy way of doing it. Try running the latest revision of my code.

Comment: wow it looks really good thanks so much...I have one small question...is there any way to change all the text in the file to lowercase, because it is pulling COM Com and com as different values.  I put in re.IGNORECASE in the search string, but it didn't seem to matter

Comment: @kegewe Yes, just add .lower() to the dict keys. See my updated answer.

Comment: @kegewe I alse added sorting of the data based on the date column using `dateutil.parser.parse` :)