# creating proper tsv output from dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have a server log file, linked [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/svq64i27b75l4fu/access_log.txt)

my goal is to find "valid" server visits, and write a summary valid top-level domains to an output file.

The output file must be a .tsv file.  An example file is linked [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yktd1gfve4c6jnk/valid_log_ideal.txt)

I have gotten the results of my regex (which definitely still needs some tweaking) into a dictionary of dictionaries, in order to conform to the desired output.  My problem is sorting the dictionary keys alphabetically by the inner dictionary keys (the top-level domains), and then doing the same for the outer dictionary keys (the date).  additionally, I'm not sure how to sneak the "\t" character in between each key/value pair.

I know that dictionaries are unsortable, I'm just having difficulty moving the data into a sortable format, and then writing the output into a style that conforms to the example file

I have included my code thus far below:

```
import re

fhandle=open("access_log.txt", "rU")
access_log=fhandle.readlines()

validfile=open("valid.tsv", "w")
invalidfile=open("invalid.tsv", "w")

valid_list=list()
valid_dict=dict()

invalid_list=list()

#write results into respective log files
for line in access_log:
    valid=re.findall(r'(\d+/[a-zA-Z]+/\d+).*?(GET|POST)\s(http://|https://)([a-zA-Z]+)\.(\w+)\.((?<=com)\.[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+).*?(200)', line)

    if valid:
        date=valid[0][0]
        domain=valid[0][5]
        #writes results into 2d dcitonary (dictionary of dictonaries)
        if date not in valid_dict:
            valid_dict[date]={}
        else:
            if domain in valid_dict[date]:
                valid_dict[date][domain]+=1
            else:
                valid_dict[date][domain]=1
    else:
        invalid_list.append(line)




for k,v in valid_dict.items():
    valid_list.append([k,v])


for key in sorted(valid_dict.iterkeys()):
    print key, valid_dict[key]



fhandle.close()
validfile.close()
invalidfile.close()
```

Comment: Is this an assignment? Check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345254/sorting-and-organizing-a-dictionary/21345427#21345427) :)

Comment: sadly, yes.  I did find this answer online, but my issue was that I didn't quite understand each line of the code.  I'm thankful for the example, and I guess I can study what each module does, but I wasn't eager to use concepts I didn't understand.  Regardless, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering (and sleep),  I have a solution that creates output that exactly matches the example output file.

after applying the regex function and adding valid entries into a 2d dictionary, the following code properly formats and writes the output file:

```
#step 2
#format output file for tsv
#ordered chronologically, with Key:Value pairs orgainzed alphabeticallv by key (Domain Name)

date_workspace=''
domain_workspace=''

for date in sorted(valid_dict.iterkeys()):
    date_workspace+=date + "\t"

    for domain_name in sorted(valid_dict[date].iterkeys()):
        domain_workspace+="%s:%s\t" % (domain_name, valid_dict[date][domain_name])

    date_workspace+=domain_workspace
    date_workspace+="\n"    
    domain_workspace=''


# Step 3
# write output
validfile.write(date_workspace)

for line in invalid_list:
    invalidfile.write(line)
```

going line by line...

the loop will first add the date value to date_workspace, then immediately switch to iterating over the second dictionary

using the .iterkey()method makes the keys sortable.  We can now append all of our key:value pairs as strings into domain_workspace, along with the tab character in order to create the tab seperation.

once this is done concatenate our data_workspace (our string containing all of the K:V pairs) onto the date variable

lastly, we concatenate a newline character and clear out the domain_workspace in order to ensure that each date value has the correct k:v pairs attached to it.  at the end of loop, the dat_workspace variable will look something like

```
date_workspace="date\tk:v\tk:v\tk:v\t\ndate\tk:v\tk:v\tk:v\t\n"
```

is it the prettiest output?  no.  Does it do some things in a less elegant fashion than some available modules?  no.  However, it creates output that is formatted to the exact specifications of the example.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you cannot sort a dictionary. What could you use instead? Perhaps a list of keys?

In general when coding it helps to walk backwards from the solution. You goal is to write a summary. What do you need for the summary? Stub it out:

```
def write_summary(data):
    # output summary
    print data
```

Now where would `data` come from? Start simple, add complexity.